# Is there any way to programmatically toggle syntax highlighting?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to programmatically toggle syntax highlighting?  The best I can do is set the language to text.  I'm trying to duplicate this functionality I have assigned to my <kbd>F3</kbd> key in VIM:

```
map <silent> <F3> :if exists("syntax_on") <Bar> syntax off <Bar> else <Bar> syntax on <Bar> endif <CR>
```

I searched and could not find any way to do this.

Comment: I copied the wrong line in my vim file.  Here's the line in vim which handles toggling syntax highlighting:

map <silent> <F3> :if exists("syntax_on") <Bar> syntax off <Bar> else <Bar> syntax on <Bar> endif <CR>

But the question remains the same -- Is there any way to toggle syntax highlighting in VS Code?

Comment: Instead of adding that information in a comment, you should edit the post to fix that. Not everyone will read all comments and see what you posted here...

Comment: I don't see a way to edit the original post.  I must be missing it.